# Odd spacing of two column tables & lists

Tags: tables, spacing, two-column

I have an issue with the spacing of the first multiple choice question in my `MWE`. I have NO idea what is going on. I have run into issues of this sort before, but it was because of improper line breaks. However, those issues are not present here. What is happening? I am definitely interested in a detailed explanation as well if possible.

The issue is displayed in the image:
[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol,tabularx,enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0pt}
\setenumerate[1]{label={(\Alph*)}}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt}
\newlist{choicelist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[choicelist]{label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=5mm}


\begin{document}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{cX}
1.  &       MICROBE: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       large marine animal
        \item       in order of time
        \item       tiny creature
        \item       no government
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
2.  &       INSCRIBE: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item   someone who tells stories
        \item       to write on something
        \item       indiscriminate
        \item       delete
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
3.  &       GEODE: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item   rock with a crystal inside
        \item       study of life
        \item       across nations
        \item       reptilian
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
\columnbreak
4.  &       PROPEL: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       to push forward
        \item       to agree with something
        \item       proper
        \item       overly enthusiastic
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
5.  &       AUTONOMY: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       charitable act
        \item       book written by more than one person
        \item       government that rules itself
        \item       recurring
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
6.  &       TRANSGRESS: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       disagree
        \item       cross line of property
        \item       eliminate
        \item       cause an accident
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
\columnbreak
7.  &       AMORAL: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       unable to decide
        \item       uncomfortable
        \item       a vague amount
        \item       having no morals
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
8.  &       COMINGLE: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       direct
        \item       incorrect
        \item       repeating action
        \item       mix together
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
9.  &       ANARCHY: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       a government that rules itself
        \item       a book written about yourself
        \item       no government
        \item       a type of bridge
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first multiple choice item is the start of a paragraph.  The remaining questions are not separate paragraphs, but part of the first paragraph and therefore there is no indentation.

You can either place `\noindent` before the first question, or (since you say you like the appearance of the first question) you can place `\par` or a linebreak after each of the `tabularx` environments.

I would suggest that you define an environment for your questions.  Something like,

```
\newcounter{myquestioncounter}
\newenvironment{myquestion}[1]
    {%
      \tabularx{\linewidth}{cX}%
      \stepcounter{myquestioncounter}\themyquestioncounter.\ 
      & #1: \\ & 
    }
    {%   
      \endtabularx
      \par
     }
```

It will better automate a lot of what you're trying to accomplish.  You'll be able to write:

```
\begin{myquestion}{MICROBE}
  \begin{choicelist}
    \item       large marine animal
    \item       in order of time
    \item       tiny creature
    \item       no government
  \end{choicelist}
\end{myquestion}
```

Or if you load the `environ` package, you can do this a bit more efficiently,

```
\NewEnviron{varquestion}[1]
    {
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}%
      \stepcounter{myquestioncounter}\themyquestioncounter.\ 
      & #1: \\ & 
      \begin{choicelist}
      \BODY
      \end{choicelist}
      \end{tabularx}\par
    }
```

and then format your questions as

```
\begin{varquestion}{INSCRIBE}
    \item someone who tells stories
    \item to write on something
    \item indiscriminate
    \item delete
\end{varquestion}
```

The *question* argument can contain text that needs to wrap, but then you probably don't want the `:` at the end of the sentence.  So you can redefine the environment as

```
\NewEnviron{varquestion}[2][:]
    {
      \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{cX}%
      \stepcounter{myquestioncounter}\themyquestioncounter.\ 
      & #2#1 \\ & 
      \begin{choicelist}
      \BODY
      \end{choicelist}
      \end{tabularx}\hspace*{1em}\par
    }
```

where the first argument is optional and assumes that you'll end the question with a `:`, but you can call it as:

```
\begin{varquestion}[]{This is just a random question that may span more
than one line of the final document. }
    \item someone who tells stories
    \item to write on something
    \item indiscriminate
    \item delete
\end{varquestion}
```

Also, I changed the width of the `tabularx` environment since otherwise the text will run right up against the `\columnseprule`.

## A complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%..%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0pt}
\setenumerate[1]{label={(\Alph*)}}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt}
\newlist{choicelist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[choicelist]{label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=5mm,topsep=-3ex}
%..%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{environ}
\newcounter{myquestioncounter}
\NewEnviron{testquestion}[2][:]
    {%
      \begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-1em}{cX}%
      \stepcounter{myquestioncounter}\themyquestioncounter.\ 
      & #2#1 \\ & 
      \begin{choicelist}
      \BODY
      \end{choicelist}
      \end{tabularx}\hspace*{1em}\par
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{testquestion}{MICROBE}
    \item       large marine animal
    \item       in order of time
    \item       tiny creature
    \item       no government
\end{testquestion}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{testquestion}{INSCRIBE}
    \item someone who tells stories
    \item to write on something
    \item indiscriminate
    \item delete
\end{testquestion}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{testquestion}[]{This is just a random question that may span more
than one line of the final document. }
    \item someone who tells stories
    \item to write on something
    \item indiscriminate
    \item delete
\end{testquestion}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{testquestion}{GEODE}
        \item rock with a crystal inside
        \item study of life
        \item across nations
        \item reptilian
\end{testquestion}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{testquestion}{PROPEL}
        \item to push forward
        \item to agree with something
        \item proper
        \item overly enthusiastic
\end{testquestion}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{testquestion}{AUTONOMY}
        \item       charitable act
        \item       book written by more than one person
        \item       government that rules itself
        \item       recurring
\end{testquestion}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{testquestion}{TRANSGRESS}
        \item       disagree
        \item       cross line of property
        \item       eliminate
        \item       cause an accident
\end{testquestion}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{testquestion}{AMORAL}
        \item       unable to decide
        \item       uncomfortable
        \item       a vague amount
        \item       having no morals
\end{testquestion}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{testquestion}{COMINGLE}
        \item       direct
        \item       incorrect
        \item       repeating action
        \item       mix together
\end{testquestion}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{testquestion}{ANARCHY}
        \item       a government that rules itself
        \item       a book written about yourself
        \item       no government
        \item       a type of bridge
\end{testquestion}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks. I just switched the `cls` and it brought the indent back. Thought I had disabled it. Should I delete this question, it seems quite specific now that I understand the solution?

Comment: Wow! Now that's clean. I appreciate the further refinement. With this macro/environ will the text wrap appropriately if the 'question' is in fact several sentences instead of a single word?

Comment: And, how will the counter for the question number reset in future usages. I am typesetting a large test prep booklet with various types of questions that are multiple choice.

Comment: I got the first solution to work. But the `environ` suggestion does not typeset. It doesn't like the counter or the environment for some reason.

Comment: Have you copied and pasted the code?  When I come back, I'll post the complete example with preamble and all.  Do note that the syntax for `environ`  environments is a bit different from that of `\newenvironment` command.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{multicol,tabularx,enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0pt}
\setenumerate[1]{label={(\Alph*)}}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{15pt}
\newlist{choicelist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[choicelist]{label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=5mm}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{multicols}{2}\noindent % \noindent here
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{cX}
1.  &       MICROBE: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       large marine animal
        \item       in order of time
        \item       tiny creature
        \item       no government
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
2.  &       INSCRIBE: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item   someone who tells stories
        \item       to write on something
        \item       indiscriminate
        \item       delete
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
3.  &       GEODE: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item   rock with a crystal inside
        \item       study of life
        \item       across nations
        \item       reptilian
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
\columnbreak
4.  &       PROPEL: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       to push forward
        \item       to agree with something
        \item       proper
        \item       overly enthusiastic
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
5.  &       AUTONOMY: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       charitable act
        \item       book written by more than one person
        \item       government that rules itself
        \item       recurring
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
6.  &       TRANSGRESS: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       disagree
        \item       cross line of property
        \item       eliminate
        \item       cause an accident
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
\columnbreak
7.  &       AMORAL: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       unable to decide
        \item       uncomfortable
        \item       a vague amount
        \item       having no morals
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
8.  &       COMINGLE: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       direct
        \item       incorrect
        \item       repeating action
        \item       mix together
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
9.  &       ANARCHY: \\
&   \begin{choicelist}
        \item       a government that rules itself
        \item       a book written about yourself
        \item       no government
        \item       a type of bridge
    \end{choicelist}
\end{tabularx}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```